# Usb pen drive can't be formatted and turn off all the usb ports

Tags: partitioning, usb

I'm trying to format a usb pen drive.

[image]

Once i select NTF or FAT, starts the process and then this error pops up

[image]

And after that, all the usb ports stopped working, so i need to turn the pc off and on again to make everything work again.

I also tried GParted and the same happened (tried MS-DOs and MAC) and also the usb ports stopped working.

[image]

Also tried an answer from here, but still the same.

[image]

**Is my USB usless now or is there a way to save it?**

[image]

Ubuntu 20.04

**Edit 1**

I tried with everything disconnected (usb ports) and i had this new error.

[image]

I also tried to format the usb with a Mac, Windows Pc and even my phone (Android) via Usb C converter and nothing happens there... So it's probably my pendrive?

Comment: "the usb ports stopped working" ⇠ this strikes me as hardware failure. Do you see any messages in `/var/log/syslog` from the time when the formatting of the USB disk failed? If your computer loses the entire USB subsystem, there should be *a lot* of failure/warning/critical messages in the logs saying why something has failed. [Edit] your question to include these log details, as well as the brand/model of computer you're using and which version of Ubuntu you run. With this, it may be possible to offer a solution 

Comment: @matigo Edited now, thanks

Comment: Based on some preliminary research, the `Not enough bandwidth` message is due to the USB channels being over provisioned. How many USB devices does your machine have connect to it at any given time? If you are using a slightly-older notebook on battery power, the USB controller will reduce the amount of power/data-transfer available to the entire bus, which can lead to issues if you have a bunch of unpowered (or very busy) hubs connected 

Comment: @matigo i have 3: Keyboard, mouse, and wacom tablet... and the charger is plugged in

Comment: Still looking for an answer for this, before I throw my pen drive to the garbage